# How to plot top n highest values in a bar graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib

I have realtime data with three values : id, name, salary. I'm plotting a graph for it using name and salary.

```
def graph():
    con = None
    try:
        con = connect("project.db")
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "select name, salary from employee"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        name = []
        salary = []
        for i in data:
            name.append(i[0])
            salary.append(i[1])
        plt.bar(name, salary)
        plt.xlabel("Names of Employee")
        plt.ylabel("Salary of Employee")
        plt.title("Top 5 Highest Salaried Employee")
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("issue ", e)
        con.rollback()
    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
```

But my issue is : i get the bar graph for all employees. I only want to plot for the 5 highest paid employees. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your results from the SQL query by ascending on salary, and then only take the top five results.

Try `'''SELECT name, salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 5'''`